# How to export libGDX Gradle copied files out of workspace back to original project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

In libGDX, it originally creates Gradle files into a folder specified by the user and the user imports the files into their workspace by using Gradle. LibGDX tells its users not to copy the files into the workspace for multiple Gradle reasons, unfortunately however, I did not listen in an older project.

The workspace files in Eclipse are different than those in the original Gradle build of the project, is there a way to reverse this and export the workspace files back into the original folder?

If not, can I remove the Eclipse workspace files, re-import the Gradle project the right way, and then move all the workspace files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this quite annoying issue. What I did was simply move the Eclipse project files out of the workspace in File Explorer into a safe spot and then delete them out of the Eclipse workspace using the Eclipse explorer. Then, I re-imported the original unedited Gradle project back into the workspace, not copying the files in this time like I was supposed to. Then, I went and copied the Eclipse source files out of the old and moved workspace folders and pasted the files over the source and bin of the Gradle core project files.

Note: If you deleted the original Gradle libGDX project files, just recreate it quickly using the libGDX project creator.